# Silver Coating on the front glass inside a crt

Tags: monitor, crt, mac

I recently disassembled a defective Macintosh SE. When taking apart the CRT (safely) to preserve the front glass panel to screw back in, i noticed a silver coating on the inside of said front glass panel. When going over it with a wet towel it came right off, what could that have been?

Cheers!

Comment: There's nothing safe about taking a CRT apart, especially as you have no idea what's inside it. It's the fluorescent coating that lights up when struck by electrons.

Comment: Are you saying that you broke the vacuum? Or something else?